# MixItUp not filtering by classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixitup

I've been following the docs on the [MixItUp website](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/get-started/).

I'm using WordPress to help create the classes on each item that needs to be filtered.

This is located in my content-upcoming-games.php

```
<div class="controls col-md-12">
   <label>Sort By:</label>

   <button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>
   <button class="filter" data-filter=".ps4">PS4</button>
   <button class="filter" data-filter=".xbox-one">Xbox One</button>
   <button class="filter" data-filter=".wii-u">Wii U</button>
   <button class="filter" data-filter=".pc">PC</button>
</div>

<?php if(is_post_type_archive( 'upcoming-games' )) {
   $class ='';
   $consoles_slug = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID,  'consoles' );
   foreach ($consoles_slug as $console_slug) {
   $class .= $console_slug->slug . ' ';
   } }
?>

<div id="upcoming-games-list">
   <div class="mix <?php echo $class ?>">
      Content
   </div>
</div>
```

This is located in my main.js:

```
$('#upcoming-games-list').mixItUp({
        animation: {
        enable: true,
        effects: 'fade scale',
        duration: 600,
        easing: 'ease',
        perspectiveDistance: '3000px',
        perspectiveOrigin: '50% 50%',
        queue: true,
        queueLimit: 1,
        animateChangeLayout: false,
        animateResizeContainer: true,
        animateResizeTargets: false,
        staggerSequence: null,
        reverseOut: false
        }
    });
```

The php is working, when I inspect the code it's outputting the classes as I have them named in the `data-filter`. So the issue basically is, when I click on the button, it doesn't filter the content appropriately. For a live example, click [here](http://www.stepyouraimup.com/upcoming-games/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your items should be hidden by CSS. So, add this to make it work correctly:

```
#upcoming-games-list > .row > div {
    display: none;
}
```

In their [DOCs](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/get-started/#hide-target-elements) they say:

> Before we get to the fun part, there’s one small but crucial CSS rule
>   we must add to our project’s stylesheet to hide our target elements.

```
#Container .mix{
    display: none;
}
```

> » Target elements must be hidden by default in your project's
>   stylesheet.

Comment: Interesting solution. I've used MixItUp before and did not have to do this, but this works. Thanks.

Comment: @DarrenBachan, could be this is some new version, but in their DOCs they specify what you should do with elements (to hide them).

Comment: Wow, you are correct, that was what I missed, I did in fact have the display none applied to my .mix on the other site I worked on. Can't believe I missed that, but now I'll never forget. Thank you!